# How to wait until text box is empty selenium java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

My scenario is

1. enter the value in the text box.
2. click on the clear button.
3. wait until the text box is clear.

Comment: I can use Thread. sleep but I don't want to use it.

Comment: Try using [`textMatches`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#textMatches(org.openqa.selenium.By,java.util.regex.Pattern)) with Explicit wait. match with empty/blank string

Comment: used wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElement(webelement, "")); but still issue is same.

Comment: try using textMatches as suggested

Comment: Any of `org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions` has to be false at the moment of call otherwise it will throw `org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException`.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public static Boolean textMatchTest(WebDriver driver, By locator, String expectedText) {
    Boolean textMatch = null;
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(locator);
    if (element.getText().equals(expectedText)) {
        textMatch = true;
    }
    else {
        try {
            new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(textToBe(locator, expectedText));
            textMatch = true;
        }
        catch (TimeoutException timeoutException) {
            textMatch = false;
        }
    }
    return textMatch;
}
```